# Autofill users informations in the database in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

When a client subscribe on our website, we would like to create many rows in the database in function belonging to this user. For example, some example post, etc., to show him how the product is working.

It seems to be almost the same function than the database-seeding (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations#database-seeding) but it should be for users, and not for the application.

What is the correct way to handle this ?

Comment: When the user registers I would use a helper function to add some default data to the database and link it to the users id.

Comment: Yes, seeding is what you need. Define `should be for users`.

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this in a repository class that handles creation and modification of persistent data models.  You might just add a parameter to your create function that will populate seed data after each input.

```
<?php

class UsersRepository
{
    /**
     * Create
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return User
     */
    public function create(array $data, $seed = false)
    {
        //$this->validate($data);
        //$data = $this->clean($data);
        $user = User::create($data);
        if ($seed)
            $user = $this->seed($user);
        return $user;
    }

     /**
     * Seed
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @return User
     */
    public function seed(array $user)
    {
        // Modify user to add required attributes
        $user->base_functions = 'some_base_function';
        return $user;
    }
}
```